# Pass model to RouteValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this model:

```
public class ReportConfiguration
{
    public DateTime ReportStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReportEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to pass both values via `RouteValueCollection` to the controller?

I would like to have this method signature in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Read_Reports([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ReportConfiguration config);
```

I tried this:

```
new { area = "ReportCashRegister", config = MyInctanceOfReportConfiguration }
```

But it is resulting in a querystring variable like `config=Namespace.ReportConfiguration` instead of `ReportConfiguration.ReportStart=value` and `ReportConfiguration.ReportEnd=value`

I want to avoid to copy each property into the method signature like this: (Because my Model is an example and has much more properties I need to copy)

```
public ActionResult Read_Reports([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, DateTime reportStart, DateTime reportEnd);
```

Comment: What is under `MyInctanceOfReportConfiguration`? If it's your View code i belive there should be something like `Model.MyInctanceOfReportConfiguration`?

Comment: is the action a POST or GET

Comment: Basicly it is `new ReportConfiguration { ReportStart = DateTime.Now, ReportEnd = DateTime.Now } ` @teovankot

Comment: What is `DataSourceRequest `? because it looks like you are trying to send two models in your post

Comment: It is needed for ajax for the [KendoGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index) @Nkosi

Comment: can you show full helper line of `new { area = "ReportCashRegister", config = MyInctanceOfReportConfiguration }`?

Comment: You can also use TempData['yourname'] to hold your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action

```
public ActionResult Read_Reports([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [FromBody]ReportConfiguration config);
```

In View

```
new { area = "ReportCashRegister", ReportStart = @DateTime.Now, ReportEnd = @DateTime.Now }
```

It will add those values to the `RouteValueDictionary` and bind them to the model/parameter in the action.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is it possible to map the parameters in the `RouteValueDictionary` automaticly, or do I need to write my own reflection helper for this?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by map automatically

Comment: I mean that I can give my Model `ReportConfiguration` to the `RouteValueDictionary`, so I do not need to write `ReportStart = ReportConfiguration.ReportStart , ReportEnd = ReportConfiguration.ReportEnd`

Comment: From the view? not to my knowledge.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, Yes, you can just use `new { Model }` and the method will serialize all your model properties - but it will not work if you model contains properties which are complex objects or collections. You also need to consider that you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception is the model contains a lot of properties or the value of your properties are long strings